# mysql union all not working

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union-all

Using the MySQL code below along with ORDER BY is not working. I've searched and tried various version of the code (UNION, UNION ALL, with brackets, without brackets, a SELECT wrapping all the SELECT UNION ALLs then sorting that) - no luck. Any other suggestions?

```
        (SELECT FORMAT(lt.`rets_111`, 0) AS 'ListPrice', lt.`rets_128` AS 'MlsNumber', lt.`rets_13` AS 'Address', lt.`rets_2044` AS 'PublicRemarks', lt.`rets_sysid`, @real_estate_type:='res' AS real_estate_type,
    lt.`rets_2362` AS 'OpenHouseDate1', lt.`rets_2364` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime1', lt.`rets_2366` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime1', lt.`rets_2370` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse1',
    lt.`rets_2372` AS 'OpenHouseDate2', lt.`rets_2374` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime2', lt.`rets_2376` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime2', lt.`rets_2380` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse2'
    FROM res_listings AS lt
    WHERE lt.`rets_32` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_2337` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_1836` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2'))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT FORMAT(lt.`rets_111`, 0) AS 'ListPrice', lt.`rets_128` AS 'MlsNumber', lt.`rets_13` AS 'Address', lt.`rets_2044` AS 'PublicRemarks', lt.`rets_sysid`, @real_estate_type:='con' AS real_estate_type,
    lt.`rets_2362` AS 'OpenHouseDate1', lt.`rets_2364` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime1', lt.`rets_2366` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime1', lt.`rets_2370` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse1',
    lt.`rets_2372` AS 'OpenHouseDate2', lt.`rets_2374` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime2', lt.`rets_2376` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime2', lt.`rets_2380` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse2'
    FROM con_listings AS lt
    WHERE lt.`rets_32` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_2337` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_1836` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2'))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT FORMAT(lt.`rets_111`, 0) AS 'ListPrice', lt.`rets_128` AS 'MlsNumber', lt.`rets_13` AS 'Address', lt.`rets_2044` AS 'PublicRemarks', lt.`rets_sysid`, @real_estate_type:='mul' AS real_estate_type,
    lt.`rets_2362` AS 'OpenHouseDate1', lt.`rets_2364` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime1', lt.`rets_2366` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime1', lt.`rets_2370` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse1',
    lt.`rets_2372` AS 'OpenHouseDate2', lt.`rets_2374` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime2', lt.`rets_2376` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime2', lt.`rets_2380` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse2'
    FROM mul_listings AS lt
    WHERE lt.`rets_32` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_2337` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_1836` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2'))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT FORMAT(lt.`rets_111`, 0) AS 'ListPrice', lt.`rets_128` AS 'MlsNumber', lt.`rets_13` AS 'Address', lt.`rets_2044` AS 'PublicRemarks', lt.`rets_sysid`, @real_estate_type:='rnt' AS real_estate_type,
    lt.`rets_2362` AS 'OpenHouseDate1', lt.`rets_2364` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime1', lt.`rets_2366` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime1', lt.`rets_2370` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse1',
    lt.`rets_2372` AS 'OpenHouseDate2', lt.`rets_2374` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime2', lt.`rets_2376` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime2', lt.`rets_2380` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse2'
    FROM rnt_listings AS lt
    WHERE lt.`rets_32` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_2337` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_1836` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2'))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT FORMAT(lt.`rets_111`, 0) AS 'ListPrice', lt.`rets_128` AS 'MlsNumber', lt.`rets_13` AS 'Address', lt.`rets_2044` AS 'PublicRemarks', lt.`rets_sysid`, @real_estate_type:='ici' AS real_estate_type,
    lt.`rets_2362` AS 'OpenHouseDate1', lt.`rets_2364` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime1', lt.`rets_2366` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime1', lt.`rets_2370` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse1',
    lt.`rets_2372` AS 'OpenHouseDate2', lt.`rets_2374` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime2', lt.`rets_2376` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime2', lt.`rets_2380` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse2'
    FROM ici_listings AS lt
    WHERE lt.`rets_32` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_2337` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_1836` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2'))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT FORMAT(lt.`rets_111`, 0) AS 'ListPrice', lt.`rets_128` AS 'MlsNumber', lt.`rets_13` AS 'Address', lt.`rets_2044` AS 'PublicRemarks', lt.`rets_sysid`, @real_estate_type:='far' AS real_estate_type,
    lt.`rets_2362` AS 'OpenHouseDate1', lt.`rets_2364` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime1', lt.`rets_2366` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime1', lt.`rets_2370` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse1',
    lt.`rets_2372` AS 'OpenHouseDate2', lt.`rets_2374` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime2', lt.`rets_2376` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime2', lt.`rets_2380` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse2'
    FROM far_listings AS lt
    WHERE lt.`rets_32` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_2337` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_1836` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2'))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT FORMAT(lt.`rets_111`, 0) AS 'ListPrice', lt.`rets_128` AS 'MlsNumber', lt.`rets_13` AS 'Address', lt.`rets_2044` AS 'PublicRemarks', lt.`rets_sysid`, @real_estate_type:='lot' AS real_estate_type,
    lt.`rets_2362` AS 'OpenHouseDate1', lt.`rets_2364` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime1', lt.`rets_2366` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime1', lt.`rets_2370` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse1',
    lt.`rets_2372` AS 'OpenHouseDate2', lt.`rets_2374` AS 'OpenHouseStartTime2', lt.`rets_2376` AS 'OpenHouseEndTime2', lt.`rets_2380` AS 'DisplayOpenHouse2'
    FROM lot_listings AS lt
    WHERE lt.`rets_32` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_2337` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2') OR lt.`rets_1836` IN ('AGENT1', 'AGENT2'))

    ORDER BY 'ListPrice' DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `order by`:

```
ORDER BY 'ListPrice' DESC
```

It is ordering by a constant string.  Try this:

```
ORDER BY ListPrice DESC
```

And, in the future, only use single quotes for string and date constant values.  Never, ever for the names of things in the database.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what in the code are you referring to regarding single quotes and how they should be used?

Comment: @user3299111 . . . The single quotes are the `'` that appear around `ListPrice`.  This causes the column name to be treated as a constant value, which is not useful for sorting.

Comment: So if there are no spaces in the name I don't need quotes of any kind?

Comment: If the name is not a reserved word in SQL (like "like", "in", "select", "from", "between", and so on) and you only use alphanumeric characters, digits, and underscores, then you do not need to quote the variable name.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind, what about the backticks I am using? Necessary as a precaution and habit to be using in case a reserved word is used?

Comment: @user3299111 . . . The backticks are ok, but unnecessary.  You should get rid of the single quotes in expressions like `AS 'OpenHouseDate2'`.  That is where you would use no quotes, backticks (MySQL's preference), or double quotes (accepted in MySQL and standard across most databases).